# Can't enter data in to the database using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is the php file that going to enter data into the mysql database. When I run it, browser shows "connected successfully selected successfully Executing inside fileNot Inserted". but it's not going to show any errors. And data is not insert in to the database.  What's wrong with this code. 
*dbConnection.php

```
  <?php
        $dbhost="localhost";
        $dbuser="root";
        $dbPassword="123";
        $database="medicalcenter";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbPassword) or die("unable to connect");
         if($connection){
            echo 'connected successfully ';
        }else{
            echo 'not connected';
        }

        $dbSelect=mysqli_select_db($connection,$database);
        if($dbSelect){
            echo 'selected successfully';
        }else{
            echo 'not selected';
        } 
?>
```

*insert.php

```
<?php
    include 'dbConnection.php';
    echo "Executing inside file";
    $firstName = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'firstname');
    $secondName = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'lastname');
    $address1 =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'address1');
    $address2 =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'address2');
    $city =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'city');
    $email =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');
    $age =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'age');
    $gender =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'gender');


    $sql= "INSERT INTO    patient(FirstName,LastName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,Email,Age,Gender) VALUES ('$firstName','$secondName','$address1','$address2','$city',$email','$age','$gender')";


    if(mysqli_query($connection,$sql)){
        echo 'Inserted successfully';
    }else{
        echo 'Not Inserted';
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);


  ?>
```

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: can you please 1. put this line after echo 'Not Inserted';  printf("Message d'erreur : %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
2.  put this as first line of your file dbConnection.php: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: First thing there is no need select database separably mysqli_connect() 4th parameter is database name it self.

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. `filter_input()` is _not_ a secure way to filter inputs for database enties.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $sql= "INSERT INTO    patient(FirstName,LastName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,Email,Age,Gender) VALUES ('$firstName','$secondName','$address1','$address2','$city',$email','$age','$gender')";
```

check your above line you have forgot `'` before email please check with below line. may it helps you.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO    patient(FirstName,LastName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,Email,Age,Gender) VALUES ('$firstName','$secondName','$address1','$address2','$city','$email','$age','$gender')";
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dinesh Bhojvoni.. You save my time... :)